# Expected number of trials until the first outcome reoccurs

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The actual homework question is, "Find the expected number of tosses of a biased coin until the first outcome recurs." However, please DO NOT answer this question. I do not want to cheat, so I will ask the question in it's general form, ignoring the action (toss), object (coin), and object property (biased).

Let there be $x$ possible outcomes in one trial. What is the expected number of trials until the outcome of the first trial reoccurs?

I feel like this has to do with Geometric distribution.

Comment: Well, just condition on the first outcome.  If $\{p_i\}$ are the probabilities of the possible outcomes, then the answer is the sum of $p_i$ times the expected time to see outcome $i$ (plus $1$ for the first toss).

Comment: @lulu How can it be the sum of $p_i$? If $a=\mathrm{P}\left(\texttt{H}\right)$ and $b=\mathrm{P}\left(\texttt{T}\right)$, then the sum of $p_i$ would be $1$. So, using Geometric distribution, I would be computing $1+\frac{1}{p}+1$. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Oh wait, are you saying the following: Say the number of possible outcomes is $2$. Then the solution is $\left[\left(p_{1}\times\frac{1}{p_{1}}\right)+1\right]+\left[\left(p_{2}\times\frac{1}{p_{2}}\right)+1\right]$. Or in general, $\sum_{i=1}^{x}\left[\left(p_{i}\times\frac{1}{p_{i}}\right)+1\right]$.

Comment: Well, you've got the $1$ in the wrong place.  It should be outside the sum (or, equivalently, multiplied by $p_i$).  Otherwise, that's it.

Comment: @lulu Got it! So, $1+\sum_{i=1}^{x}\left(p_{i}\times\frac{1}{p_{i}}\right)$, correct? That would mean the answer to the professors question is $3$.

Comment: Yes, that's right.  Note that this is "clearly" true for a fair coin

Comment: Yes, I realized that. All that must stay constant for the general formula to work is $\left\{ p_{i}\right\}$ is the same in each trial.

Comment: Oh, yes.  If the probabilities change with the trials then all bets are off.